# How do I get text to display the same on different devices?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get text on the iPad and iPhone to look the same. I used MediaQuery to make the font proportionate to the iPad screen but then it was too big on the iPhone. So I used AutoSizeText but now I get this problem.

[image: What I want vs what I'm getting]

Here's my code:

```
body: ListView(children: [
        Center(
          child: AutoSizeText('Dummy Text',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60 * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio),
            maxLines: 1,),
        ),

        Divider(
        ),

        Center(
          child: AutoSizeText('Dummy',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60 * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio),
            maxLines: 1,),
        ),

        Divider(
        ),

        Center(
          child: AutoSizeText('Dummy Text Text',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60 * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio),
            maxLines: 1,),
        ),
      ],
      ),
```

Comment: Why are you not just using a static fontSize?

Comment: What is a static fontSize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust your Text according to **screen width** you should try the below code snippet in your Application.

```
 fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 500 ?60 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 300 ?40:30
```

The above statement means that,

- when your **screen width** is greater than **500** then show
  **textSize** **60**
- if less than **300**, then show **textSize** **30**
- Else between **500** and **300** shows **textSize**  **40**